# AICharacterControl unity c#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Помогите мне пожалуйста со скриптом c# unity выдаёт ошибку:

> error CS0246: The type or namespase name "NavMeshAgent" could

Comment: Дополните вопрос, ничего не понятно, что вы делаете? После чего появилась ошибка? Чего вы хотите добиться? Добавьте код.

Answer (score 1):

В верху скрипта наверное надо добавить

```
using UnityEngine.AI;
```

Answer (score 0):

Не могу вспомнить почему это появлялось но решалось так - нужно зайти в раздел `Navigation` и нажать ещё раз `Bake`, На всякий случай вот вам картинка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]